# Bluetooth speaker works only when aux is plugged in

Tags: bluetooth, speakers, repair

## Plot

Recently got this **Bluetooth/FM speaker with a built-in microphone** from my friend to try repairing it. He said that it's battery was swollen up so he dumped the battery and never used the speaker again.(*old phone battery 3.7V i guess.*) [[image]I believe it's "something" X6 by a Chinese manufacturer.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sK7PS.jpg)

## Problem

1. I plugged the USB cable, without a battery, just to saw that it goes on and off, constantly. No sound comes out of it except speakers powering on and off.
2. Then I tried to plug my headphones to it's AUX input, voila! I heard the Asian chick going: *"Bluetooth device is ready to pair."*
3. Paired it with my computer, played some tunes, then I plugged my headphones off and it was still working.
4. When I powered it off and turned it back on, it's all over again. Constantly going on and off.

By the way it have some low buzzing noise all the time(grounding issues, maybe?).

### Here are some pictures of the circuitry and components:

[image: Sorry for the yellow text. I don't even know what most of the components do.]

[image: Here is another picture.]

I'm kind of a newbie in here and electronics, I try to repair before throwing stuff away. And I'm curious, what is the reasoning behind this? Thanks in advance.